# Place variable in div id

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to use an incremental div id, so that all my id are unique, therefore I can use jquery effects to modify them independently.

I hope my question makes sense. If i need to elaborate please let me know.

div id ="name_$id"

---

Ok maybe I have to be more clear about my question.

Here are two divs with same id.

```
 <div id="comment">
  </div>
  <div id="comment">
  </div>
```

I want the id of the two divs to be comment1, and comment2. But automatically.

So I know I will need for example , $i to accompany  comment, like comment_$i

I also know that I will have to increment i++ after each div displayed.

I hope I am more clear.

Comment: There's actually no question ;-)

Comment: Do you *need* separate IDs? Unless you're *finding* them by ID, you can handle them separately with jQuery without this...

Answer (score 3):

easy, just use

```
<div id="name_<?php echo $id; ?>"> 
     content 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks jpabluz. Im gonna play with that now.

Answer (score 2):

something like this? You're question isn't very clear, but you can use a loop and give unique ids like so:

```
for($i=0;$i < 10;$i++;) {
    echo "<div id='idhere_$i'>";
    echo "stuff in the div";
    echo "</div>
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I am using Zen Cart, and it generates several divs, who all have the same div id.

If i want to hide all the divs, it only hides the first div. Any other div with the same div  is still displayed.

So if I have to generate several divs with a different id each.

Anyways Thanks, GSto. I think your example is what I am going to need.

<div id ="idname_.'$variablename')

So some sort of prefix followed by a variable name.

Comment: yes, or you could change is from an id to a class. no two elements should ever have the same id. Zen Cart isn't the best product when it comes to e-commerce, so it wouldn't be suprised to here of it doing something like that.

Comment: Well, I think all ecommerce packages are very similar. Where one has an advantage to others it would be at the expense of another feature. But yh is it possible that I cud send you my php file? Where I am trying to show/hide divs. It is the file I test with, so that I understand how scripts work and stuf?

Comment: No worries, I found a great tutorial on http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/expand.html

It was the expand/collapse all that i was after.

Thanks maate

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you already have it.

As a loop:

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < $some_max_value; $i++){
        echo "<div id=\"name_$id\">stuff</div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No worries, I found a great tutorial on http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/expand.html

It was the expand/collapse all that i was after.

Thanks maate